# SQL Remove all rows where one value repeats

Tags: sql

Let's assume that I have table with one column like this

```
1
1
1
2
3
4
5
5
```

I need to do something to make it look like this:

```
2
3
4
```

I can't use DISTINCT, because it will keep at least one of "1" and one of "5". So, I just want to delete everything if it has same value for that column anywhere in table.

Comment: please tag your dbms as well.

Comment: Do you actually need to **delete** rows from your table or just **exclude** from the query result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delete from your_table
where col in
(
  select col from your_table group by col having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select MyNum, count(MyNum)
from MyTable
group by MyNum
having count(MyNum) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SQL SERVER` then this can be easily achieved through `CTE` and `COUNT Over()` window aggregate function

```
;with cte as
(
Select count(1) over(partition by your_col) cnt,*
)
Delete from CTE where cnt > 1
```